# Removing elements of a stack

Tags: python, class, stack

This code is supposed to take the input of ABCDEFG and take elements out of it using stacks. For example: ADCDEFG and take out D should return ABCEFG. Not sure why it's not returning anything but []. I'm pretty sure the class stack function works, as its worked with other codes before, perhaps its in my remove function? Any suggestions? I think I need to add something else, just not quite sure what.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def __str__(self):
        temp = Stack()
        stringy = ""
        while not self.isEmpty():
            a = self.pop()
            temp.push(a)
            stringy = str(a) + stringy
        while not temp.isEmpty():
            self.push(temp.pop())
        return "["+stringy+")\n"        

def remove(Fstack, item):
    Ustack = Stack()
    #this loop will repeat itself until the stack is empty
    while Fstack.isEmpty() == False:
        out = Fstack.pop()
        #If the numbers being pushed out are NOT the target, add them to a new stack
        if out != item:
            #pushes out aka all numbers not target into Ustack aka new atack
            Ustack.push(out)
            print(Ustack)
    return Fstack                


def main():
    letters = "ABCDEFG"
    st = Stack()
    for c in letters:
        st.push(c)

    first = "D"
    st = remove(st, first)   #now st should be [ABCEFG)
    print("after first", st.items)  #cheating a bit - the stack is a list so we print it

    second = "H"
    st = remove(st, second)  #st should still be [ABCEFG)
    print("after second", st.items)

    third = "A"
    st = remove(st, third)
    print("after third", st.items)
main()
```

Comment: Your "remove" function takes all the elements out of fstack.  That's why there aren't any left.  The function also puts some elements into a new stack, but it doesn't return that. so it simply gets lost.  I don't know what you're trying to do because I can't make any sense of the first sentence of your question.  Try re-writing it.